# WPF DataGrid selected row put in list

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to put the `DataGrid` selected row all attribute to textbox.
How can I put the selected row each data to textbox?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgSearch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" Height="390" Width="Auto" MouseLeftButtonDown="dgSearch_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

[img](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/150214/Screenshot_2015-02-14_21.53.49_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected row you have two options:

1- Using `DataGridRow` to the selected row

2- Casting the selected row to the corresponding model

1:

```
DataRowView Row = (DataRowView)dataGridView.SelectedItem;
//Then 
var i = Row["Column Name"];
//Then putting to you text box
```

2:

```
CorrespondingModel model = (CorrespondingModel)dataGridView.SelectedItem;
// Then 
textBox.Text = model.PropertyX + model.ProprtyY;
```

Comment: 1.Error :Cannot Apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow'

Comment: @user3793233: Sorry for that, I accidentally typed in the wrong type. Check the update.